# How to hide default SignOut using AWS Amplify with React Native?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify in my React Native app as instructed here: https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/react-native/#using-the-authenticator-component

It is working, more or less. But when I log in there is a box saying Hello with a Sign Out button added to the project. I can get rid of this by setting hideDefault={true} but then if I log out there is no login/signup screen. My code is below, thank you for any help.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, Button,View,Platform,StatusBar,Image, TouchableWithoutFeedback, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import {useState} from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { useNavigationContainerRef } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

// Screens
import Browsescreen from './screens/Browsescreen';  

// AWS
import { Authenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react-native/dist/Auth';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function App() {
  const navigationRef = useNavigationContainerRef();
  const [showLoggedInPage, setLoggedInPage] = useState(false);

  const loggedInPage = showLoggedInPage ? (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <View>
        [REMOVED]
      </View>
      <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>        
        <Tab.Navigator>
            [REMOVED]
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaView>
  ) : null;

  return (
    <Authenticator
    onStateChange={(authState) => {
      console.log(authState)
      if (authState == "signedIn") {
        setLoggedInPage(true);
      } else {
        setLoggedInPage(false);
      }      
    }
    } 
    hideDefault={false}
    >    
    {loggedInPage}    
    </Authenticator>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ddd',
  },
});
export default App;
```

I am new to this, please make it as simple as possible and provide sample if possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/react-native/#using-withauthenticator-hoc), if you are using the HOC component `withAuthenticator`.

```
export default withAuthenticator(App, {
  // Render a sign out button once logged in
  includeGreetings: true,
});
```

The sign-out button is shown when "includeGreetings" is set to "true". Changing it to "false" will hide the sign-out button.

Answer (score 0):

//Just
export default withAuthenticator(App, false);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).